# fixing strictBindCallApply related error in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, handsontable

When I add `strictBindCallApply:true` in my `tsconfig.json` and run `ng build` I get the following:

> ERROR in src/app/hot/hot.component.ts(538,61): error TS2345: Argument of type 'IArguments' is not assignable to parameter of type '[Core, HTMLTableCellElement, number, number, string | number, any, CellProperties]'.
>   Type 'IArguments' is missing the following properties from type '[Core, HTMLTableCellElement, number, number, string | number, any, CellProperties]': 0, 1, 2, 3, and 32 more.

The pertinent code section is as follows:

```
const cellValidationTempVar = this.cellValidation;
this.cellValidation[i].renderer = function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
  Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments); // HERE!
  if (instance.getDataAtCell(row, col).length > cellValidationTempVar[col].length ) {
    td.classList.add('htInvalid');
  } else {
    td.classList.remove('htInvalid');
  }
}
```

The `Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);` statement is identical to that used in the [documentation](https://handsontable.com/docs/7.0.0/demo-custom-renderers.html).

I'm using:

- Angular 7.2
- Handsontable 7.0.0
- Typescript 3.2.4

The build works fine without `strictBindCallApply`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `strictBindCallApply:true` enables strict type checks for `apply` calls that is why it causes the error. The type of the `arguments` is not what typescript expects to get in the apply call. The sample in the documentation is a javascript sample where there is no type checking that is why it works ok.

You can prevent the error by specifying the arguments explicitly instead of using the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments). Here is the updated code:

```
const cellValidationTempVar = this.cellValidation;
this.cellValidation[i].renderer = function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
  Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, [instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties]); // HERE!
  if (instance.getDataAtCell(row, col).length > cellValidationTempVar[col].length ) {
    td.classList.add('htInvalid');
  } else {
    td.classList.remove('htInvalid');
  }
}
```

This is not so elegant but it prevents the type error.

Another option is to specify to ignore the type by casting to `any` so it is then like the javascript code.

```
Handsontable.default.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments as any);
```

If you want the type checking I think the first approach is the better way to go.